# ApplicationUser (IdentityUser) requires parameterless constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-identity

I have a .NET Core 3.1 MVC web app using Identity UI 3.1, EF Core 3.1. I have an ApplicationUser class that inherits from IdentityUser and adds some properties. When I attempt to register a new user using the default Identity UI, I get the following error:

*InvalidOperationException: Can't create an instance of 'TUser'. Ensure that 'TUser' is not an abstract class and has a parameterless constructor, or alternatively override the register page in /Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Register.cshtml*

When I add a public parameterless constructor to ApplicationUser, it works fine. However, I really don't want a public parameterless constructor on ApplicationUser as I want to enforce that it has a particular state from instantiation.

Any ideas on how to get around this while still using the default Identity UI and avoiding custom-coding the Register page?

Here's the ApplicationUser class:

```
public sealed class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser, IEntity<string>
{
        public ApplicationUser(string id, string email)
        {
            Id = id;
            UserName = email;
            NormalizedUserName = email.ToUpper();
            Email = email;
            NormalizedEmail = email.ToUpper();
        }

        public AuthorizationToken TaskAuthorizationToken { get; private set; }

        public void SetTaskAuthorizationToken(AuthorizationToken token)
        {
            TaskAuthorizationToken = token;
        }

        public bool HasTaskAuthorizationToken()
        {
            return TaskAuthorizationToken != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TaskAuthorizationToken.Token);
        }

        private object Actual => this;

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (!(obj is ApplicationUser other))
                return false;

            if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
                return true;

            if (Actual.GetType() != other.Actual.GetType())
                return false;

            if (Id == string.Empty || other.Id == string.Empty)
                return false;

            return Id == other.Id;
        }

        public static bool operator ==(ApplicationUser a, ApplicationUser b)
        {
            if (a is null && b is null)
                return true;

            if (a is null || b is null)
                return false;

            return a.Equals(b);
        }

        public static bool operator !=(ApplicationUser a, ApplicationUser b)
        {
            return !(a == b);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return (Actual.GetType() + Id).GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Here's the relevant startup.cs code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
     options.UseSqlServer(
          Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
     services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
          .AddDefaultUI()
          .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

     services.AddMvc(o =>
     {
         var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
             .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
             .Build();
         o.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
     }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
}
```

Comment: the relevant code is the custom user class

Comment: @Darkonekt - I revised the question to include the actual code for ApplicationUser.

Comment: @drewob Short answer: **No**. The error message says it all. that class must have a parameterless constructor. That is how the Identity framework was designed.

Comment: No,you can't.You need have a parameterless constructor or modify your Register.cshtml.